# ServiceStack.Razor CustomHttpHandler changes StatusCode

Tags: servicestack

Given the following configuration, ServiceStack will render the `notfound` razor view and return a 200 status code when a NotFound error occurs.

How can I use the `RazorHandler` to render the `notfound` view and keep the correct 404 status code?

```cs
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    CustomHttpHandlers = {
        { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/notfound") },
        { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new RazorHandler("/login") },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notfound.cshtml :

```
@{
  this.Layout = "_YourLayout";
  this.Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```